# How to expose an asynchronous api as a custom akka stream Source now that ActorPublisher is deprecated?

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka.net

With `ActorPublisher` deprecated in favor of `GraphStage`, it looks as though I have to give up my actor-managed state for GraphStateLogic-managed state.  But with the actor managed state I was able to mutate state by sending arbitrary messages to my actor and with GraphStateLogic I don't see how to do that.

So previously if I wanted to create a Source to expose data that is made available via HTTP request/response, then with `ActorPublisher` demand was communicated to my actor by `Request` messages to which I could react by kicking off an HTTP request in the background and send responses to my actor so I could send its contents downstream.

It is not obvious how to do this with a `GraphStageLogic` instance if I cannot send it arbitrary messages.  Demand is communicated by `OnPull()` to which I can react by kicking off an HTTP request in the background.  But then when the response comes in, how do I safely mutate the GraphStateLogic's state?

*(aside: just in case it matters, I'm using Akka.Net, but I believe this applies to the whole Akka streams model.  I assume the solution in Akka is also the solution in Akka.Net.  I also assume that ActorPublisher will also be deprecated in Akka.Net eventually even though it is not at the moment.)*

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the question is referring to "**asynchronous side-channels**" and is discussed here:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-customize.html#using-asynchronous-side-channels.

> **Using asynchronous side-channels**
>
> In order to receive asynchronous events that are not arriving as stream elements (for example a completion of a future or a callback from a 3rd party API) one must acquire a `AsyncCallback` by calling `getAsyncCallback()` from the stage logic. The method `getAsyncCallback` takes as a parameter a callback that will be called once the asynchronous event fires.

Comment: The same docs for Akka.NET can be found at http://getakka.net/articles/streams/custom-stream-processing.html#using-asynchronous-side-channels